# "matrix" attribute of VML not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, transformation, vml

I am trying to add "matrix" attribute in the following example to scale the vml shape. It seems like there is some error in the way i am adding the matrix attribute. Please help.
**Note : The example would be working in IE8.**

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
    <style>
        v\:*{ behavior: url(#default#VML) }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <DIV style="HEIGHT: 400px">
    <v:oval strokecolor="red" fillcolor="yellow" matrix="10,0,0,10,0,0" style="position:relative;top:50;left:50;width:75;height:50">
    </v:oval>
    </DIV>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The matrix attribute cannot be applied to an oval. Instead, you can try to apply it to a skew inside of the oval.

There is an example [here](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/vml/shape/skew/t_skew.htm) that might be helpful. You may want to turn on Compatibility View.